# Как заполнить словарь в цикле?

Tags: python

Пытаюсь заполнить словарь из другого словаря в цикле.

```
for i in jsonData:
finalDict['executor'] = i['idMembers']
```

Но в итоге в словарь записывается только одно значение **executor**, хотя длина словаря "донора" намного больше. Проверяю это так:

```
print(json.dumps(finalDict, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(",", ": ")))
```

Но, если в цикле добавить **print(i['comments'])** то в терминал выводятся все значение.

Как мне заполнить новый словарь всеми значениями?
В итоге должно быть так:

```
[{"executor":"1"},{"executor":"2},{"executor":"3"},{...} }]
```

Comment: Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь присвоить одному ключу множество. С каждой итерацией он просто перезаписывает значение ключа.

Comment: @greymaster, я пытался делать через enumerate, чтобы использовать индекс, но ничего не получилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если следовать вашим условиям, то такое решение должно подойти.

Здесь для каждого ключа создается отдельный словарь, позже словарь добавляется в список

```
jsonData = [{'idMembers': 1}, {'idMembers': 2}, {'idMembers': 3}]  # входные данные

finalDict = list()

for i in jsonData:
    finalDict.append({"executor": i['idMembers']})

print(finalDict)
```

Answer (score 3):

Также если же вам нужно чтобы был именно словарь, то можно использовать такое решение

```
jsonData = [{'idMembers': 1}, {'idMembers': 2}, {'idMembers': 3}]

finalDict = {}

for i in jsonData:
    if "executor" not in finalDict: # Проверка на наличие ключа
        finalDict["executor"] = list()

    finalDict["executor"].append(i["idMembers"])

print(finalDict)
# вывод {'executor': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно покороче:

```py
jsonData = [{'idMembers': 1}, {'idMembers': 2}, {'idMembers': 3}]
res = [{'executor': x['idMembers']} for x in jsonData]
print(res) # [{'executor': 1}, {'executor': 2}, {'executor': 3}]
```